# How can I build an apk for react-native project?

Tags: react-native

How can I build an apk file for my react native project when the new version of CRNA integrates Expo Toolkit and android and ios folders are hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install expo in your global environment with `npm install -g exp`

If you haven't used `exp` before, the first thing you'll need to do is login with your Expo account using `exp login`.

you need to configure your app.json similar to

```
 {
   "expo": {
   "name": "Your App Name",
   "icon": "./path/to/your/app-icon.png",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "slug": "your-app-slug",
   "sdkVersion": "XX.0.0",
   "ios": {
     "bundleIdentifier": "com.yourcompany.yourappname"
   },
   "android": {
     "package": "com.yourcompany.yourappname"
  }
 }
}
```

Run `exp build:android` or exp `build:ios`

You need to follow cli options and done you can download your apk to submit to playstore

you can see expo documentation to get more info about it, but is really easy