# How can I build an APK from a React Native project without Expo?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm very new to React Native and mobile development in general and I'm building a proof-of-concept application. I don't want to deploy this to the stores, but I would like to check it on some other devices and put it in the hands of colleagues and stakeholders for testing.

For now I would just like to build the APK file for Android that others can install manually on their devices.

I've scaffolded the project with Expo's CLI and I'm aware that I can build the APK using Expo (as described in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659755/how-can-i-build-an-apk-for-react-native-project)), but I was wondering, is their a method to build it locally without involving any third party tools?

Preferably I would like to do this without ejecting. I also have an `android` folder in my project that I've generated with `npx expo run:android` but I haven't changed anything in it.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the following article `https://medium.com/geekculture/react-native-generate-apk-debug-and-release-apk-4e9981a2ea51`